# o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper : ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

i have created one stored procedure in Oracle 11g. When I am trying to execute the procedure through Spring Data JPA I am facing "o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper : ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call "MYPROCEDURE"  "

Procedure:

```
    create or replace PROCEDURE MYPROCEDURE(CURSOR_ OUT SYS_REFCURSOR, DEBIT_IN_ID IN NUMBER) is
    BEGIN
      OPEN CURSOR_ FOR
      SELECT * FROM paymentplan p where p.debit_id = DEBIT_IN_ID;
    END MYPROCEDURE;
```

Stored Procedure Calling from JPA:

```
    @Query(value = "CALL MYPROCEDURE(:DEBIT_IN_ID)", nativeQuery = true)
        List<PaymentPlan> findPlans(@Param("DEBIT_IN_ID") int debtor_id);
```

Error:

```
    Hibernate: CALL MYPROCEDURE(?)
    2021-02-09 11:55:15.464  WARN 13560 --- [nio-8055-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 6553, SQLState: 65000
    2021-02-09 11:55:15.465 ERROR 13560 --- [nio-8055-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'MYPROCEDURE'
```